# Can't add the Entity Linking API to my Azure account

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

TL;DR
Can't add the "Entity Linking API" to my Azure account for some reason.

I'm trying to add the "Entity Linking API" to my Azure account the same way I did with the Translation service. 
However, it doesn't exist in the service selection drop-down list in the console.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something, but after going over the documentation a gazillion times I can't say what.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all Cognitive Services APIs are currently available with paid offers in the Azure portal.  All APIs available through Azure are listed at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/.  From the bottom of that page you can click the **More APIs** link to take you to https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/apis which has the broader list of Cognitive Services APIs, but not all of those APIs are available in Azure.

To use the Entity Linking API you can create a free account outside of Azure by using the **Get started for free** link at https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/entity-linking-intelligence-service.