# Can't create a Linguistics API Cognitive services

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to create an Account on Cognitive Services to try out the linguistics API, however, in my Azure account the option does not appear on the API list:

[image: API List]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [Can't add the Entity Linking API to my Azure account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42536150/cant-add-the-entity-linking-api-to-my-azure-account/42536976#42536976) for the same answer.  In short, not all Cognitive APIs are available in Azure during the preview phase.  To sign up for those APIs you can do so from https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/apis.